# How to make a more complex wxWidgets save system

Tags: c++, save, wxwidgets

I'm making a desktop app with wxWidgets but I can't figure out how it can have a more complex save system. For example, a project in Sony Vegas is saved in one file, and it's a (.veg). My save system will have to save mostly text from user, but in different areas. To be able to do this, do I need to save each thing I need separatly and load them all when I wish to re-enter the app? Sorry if this question seems obvious, I'm new fairly new at using wxWidgets.

Comment: do you have a library that saves veg files? Is it some kind of a library? Just link this library and call the appropriate function on the event handler. And I'm not sure I understand the question - `more complex save system`. What do you mean by that?

Comment: @Igor No, I'm not gonna save .veg files, that was just an example of a save system. Ripi2, gave me a solution, but thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saving data to one or more files depends on how you organize your app.

- It may read data from a file only when needed. Different tasks may use different files.
- It may store everything in a single file. Read it all once. Or read parts of it for different tasks. If the file is too much big (my opinion, greater than 50 MB), obviously this is not the best option.

For the second option you may use `std <fstream>` functions. Or some of [those](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/group__group__class__file.html) provided by wxWidgets, which you will appreciate if you need to deal with text encodings, or other features as well.

Also, [wxFileConfig](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_file_config.html) may be useful if you wish to set several "sections" of your data.

Comment: Thanks for replying! That's just what I needed, I'll check them out